# Where i can find the contents of this section <?php echo $helper->getModulesByPosition('left') ?>

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, sidebar, reorder

I am using a theme name venus and here i have to find the content of sidebar to set the order of my sidebar blocks I have tried by ordering them in catalog.xml but no luck.

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
        <block type="ves_productcarousel2/list" after="catalog.leftnav" name="productcarousel2.list"/> 
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="tags_popular" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

As i want to move Compare product and Best Sellers after the product filters in sidebar.

here is the code in my page template that showing it:

```
<aside class="col-lg-<?php echo $SPAN[0];?> col-md-<?php echo $SPAN[0];?> col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div id="columns-left" class="sidebar"><?php echo $helper->getModulesByPosition('left') ?></div>
</aside>
```

Here is my site: https://www.profabrication.com/products/bends.html

Comment: can u send me email id ? so i provide the code to you

Comment: shoaibswl123@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access, then cd to magento folder and then:

```
grep -riH 'what to find' .
```

Be carefull at the final . `.`

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have just handle it with jQuery because the hierarchy was not to be changed using local.xml and catalog.xml

My Block were as follows:

```
<div class="product-ctlg-left"></div>
<div id="catalog-filters"></div>
```

Here is my jQuery Code to move my second section above

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

jQuery("#catalog-filters").insertBefore(".product-ctlg-left");  

 });
```

So it simple takes the second block and insert it before the first block.

Hope so this will help somone.